# preg_match a back slash

Tags: php, regex

```
$pattern = '/\\\p\\\/';
    if (preg_match($pattern, "\p\")) {
        echo "Correct";
    } else {
        echo "Incorrect";
    }
```

I don't understand the first \\\p. 
Why \\p does not work?

Comment: Your input string "\p\" is not correct

Comment: The pattern should be `'/\\\\p\\\\/'` and the search string should be `'\\p\\'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is wrong. pattern `\\p\\` matches the string `\p\`. But `\\\p\\\` doesn't matches anything.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zA0hE1)

If you want to match the string `\\p\\`, your pattern should be `\\\\p\\\\`.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eP5pA4)

Answer (score 0):

Note that `"\p\"` is not a valid string:

- The final `\"` escapes the quote, so that the string is not terminated
- The `\p` matches a literal `p` character, which is not what you intended
- If you want to say `\p\` in a string, you have to write it like this: `"\\p\\"`

To match `\p\`, use:

```
$regex = '~\\\\p\\\\~';
echo (preg_match($regex,"\\p\\")) ? "Matches" : "Doesn't Match";
```

See the output at the bottom of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/nOhZD0).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that both strings *and* regular expressions use escape characters and they need to be doubled in order to effect the intended behaviour.

So, in this case you need four backslashes in the regular expression and two of them in the search string:

```
if (preg_match('/\\\\p\\\\/', '\\p\\')) {
    echo "Hurray!\n";
}
```

The reason why `'/\\\p\\\/'` works is because `\p` and `\/` have no special meaning in a single quoted string and so the backslash is printed verbatim. In other words, PHP *corrects* your string to have the correct meaning; that said, you should use the correct number of escape characters.

*Btw, `"\\p\"` is just plain wrong and will cause a parse error; I'm going to assume that this was a typo.*